# How to display max file size and allowed extensions in swagger?

Tags: swagger, fastapi

How to display max file size and allowed file extensions in swagger?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/upload/')
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File()):
    ...
```

Comment: Max file size or allowed file extensions or both?

Comment: Both or something single. Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display the information, you can wrap the existing `File()` function and add a `description` to it (you can also use the existing description parameter of the `File`):

```py
from typing import Any, Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File

app = FastAPI()

def EnhancedFile(
    *args: Any,
    max_size: Optional[int] = None,
    allowed_extensions: Optional[str] = None,
    **kwargs: Any
) -> Any:
    description_details = ""
    if max_size is not None:
        description_details += "\n- max size: {} bytes".format(max_size)
    if allowed_extensions is not None:
        description_details += "\n- allowed extensions: {}".format(allowed_extensions)
    kwargs["description"] = "{}{}".format(
        kwargs.get("description", ""), description_details
    )

    return File(*args, **kwargs)


@app.post("/upload1/")
async def upload1(
    file: UploadFile = EnhancedFile(max_size=100, allowed_extensions="jpeg|pdf")
):
    ...
```

The above code only appends the specified arguments to the `description` parameter of the `File`. Which results in:

[image]

But if you want to implement the checking logics along with the descriptions, you should use [Depends()](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/):

```py
from typing import Any, Optional, Callable
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File, Depends
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
import re
from inspect import signature
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

app = FastAPI()


class Validator(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def description(self) -> str:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile) -> Any:
        pass


class AllowedExtensions(Validator):
    def __init__(self, allowed_extnesions: str) -> None:
        self._allowed_extensions = allowed_extnesions

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return "Allowed extensions: {}".format(self._allowed_extensions)

    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile) -> Any:
        if not re.match("^.*\.({})$".format(self._allowed_extensions), file.filename):
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid file extension.")
        return file


class LimitedSize(Validator):
    def __init__(self, size_limit: int) -> None:
        self._size_limit = size_limit

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return "Size limit: {}".format(self._size_limit)

    def __call__(self, file: UploadFile) -> Any:
        # Size limit logic.
        return file


def checked(initial_file: UploadFile, *validators: Validator):
    initial_file.description = "{}\n- {}".format(
        initial_file.description or "",
        "\n- ".join(validator.description for validator in validators)
    )

    def _checked(file: UploadFile = initial_file):
        for validator in validators:
            validator(file)
        return file

    return _checked

@app.post("/upload2/")
async def upload2(
    file: UploadFile = Depends(
        checked(
            File(),
            AllowedExtensions("jpeg|pdf"),
            LimitedSize(100)
        )
    )
):
    ...
```

The function `checked` is a dependency factory function that accepts a default value and some validators. At first, it adds the validators' descriptions to the file description. Also, in the actual dependency function, it runs validators over the specified file. The result of the execution of the above code is:

[image]

And as an example, returns an error when file extension is invalid:

[image]

You can also implement the file size limit using the [Content-Length header](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/362#issuecomment-584104025) but it doesn't prevent attackers to send invalid `Content-Length` value.